# How to link a CSS file from HTML file?

Tags: css, html

I have been styling my HTML with inline `<style></style>` tags in the `<head>` section. When I tried to move styles to CSS file for the first time from HTML file but, I cannot get my link to work.

I have created a new folder and inside this folder a new HTML file and CSS file are present. I am using VS Code.

I have tried pasting my HTML and my CSS into CodePen and it renders, so I know it's not an issue of the CSS itself not being correct.

**My HTML file looks like:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Try this again</title>

        <link rel="Hope this works" href="newcssstyle.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1> Here we go </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS file looks like:**

```
h1{ 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Why does linking a CSS file not work?**

In your example, **you only have to change the `rel="Hope this works"` to `rel="stylesheet"`** in order for it to recognize it as a stylesheet, as demonstrated in the following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="newcssstyle.css" type="text/css">`

Setting the `rel` attribute value to `stylesheet` distinguishes the difference between, say, a `stylesheet` link and an `icon` image link. You can see all the possible values for the `rel` attribute on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel).

---

**Furthermore**, if it still doesn't work, ensure that the file "newcssstyle.css" is in the same directory as the referenced HTML file. If you put it in a folder such as "stylesheets", ensure that you add the relative folder path to your HTML file.

**For example**, if you had a directory like this:

- Parent Directory Name:

  - *index.html*
  - Stylesheets:

    - *newcssstyle.css*

Then you would reference "newcssstyle.css" (relative to "index.css") as `href='Stylesheets/newcssstyle.css'`

Whereas, in a directory like this:

- Parent Directory Name:

  - Html_files:

    - *index.html*
  - Stylesheets:

    - *newcssstyle.css*

Then you would reference "newcssstyle.css" as `href='../Stylesheets/newcssstyle.css'` instead (where `..` means "go up one level to the parent directory").

And in a directory like this:

- Parent Directory Name:

  - *index.html*
  - *newcssstyle.css*

THen you would reference "newcssstyle.css" as `href='./newcssstyle.css'` instead (where a single `.` means "it's on the same level as the HTML file").

Answer (score -2):

`<link>` element creates relationship between current and external documents.

Important point about `<link>` i the `<link rel="">` attribute which stands for relationship. This attribute define how the linked document is related to the current document. How it is read..

Also please make sure your .css file has the same name as Your href.

You can read more about it here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link