# HTML CSS don't function

Tags: html, css

how can i link css in a html template?
Please help me, i can't figure it out, why the code don't function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: place the link tag inside head tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link a .css file from HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661749/how-to-link-a-css-file-from-html-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your css file exist in the same folder your html file. and put the link in the `<head>` or you could do your stying inside `HTML` but for good practices ALWAYS put your style files away from HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">-->
   <!--<style>
        /*or you could put test.css style*/
    </style>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to incorporate CSS to your HTML template.

**1. Inline CSS:** In this method you add a style attribute to your HTML tag, in your HTML template's code.
For example:

```
<h1 style="font-size:20px; color: blue;">Hello World</h1>
```

**2. Internal CSS:** Using internal CSS, you can incorporate styling in the HTML's head section using the style tag.
For example:

```
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size:20px; 
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```

**3. External CSS:** This is probably what you are looking for. In your folder, add an external sheet i.e. a "styles.css" file. You can add all your CSS styling in this file just as you would add in between the style tag in the head section.

**While using this method, the most important thing to do is linking your CSS file to your HTML file by adding the following line of code to your head section:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

And that should do it!