# Why does one CSS file overwrite another?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project for university where I have pomodoro-timer page, to-do list, main page. The project is made using HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

The header/navbar on the to-do page simply doesn't want to be the same style as it is on other pages.

**Here is the "style.css" which is being referenced by all pages for the header:**
*style.css*

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1rem = 10px */

    --color-primary: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-secondary: hsl(14, 100%, 66%);
    --color-font: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.902);
    --color-input: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.315);
    --color-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --color-success: hsl(115, 100%, 42%);
    --color-dropdown: hsl(0, 0%, 82%);
    --color-navbar: hsla(0, 0%, 98%, 0.987);
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    /*font-size: 1.6rem;*/
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

p,
i,
h1 {
    color: var(--color-font);
}

header{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: white;
    padding: 28px 12%;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

ul li{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo object{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.logo span{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar_folders a{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar a.navbar-link {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 1.6rem !important;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.navbar a.active{
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main a{
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

#menu-icon{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: var(--color-font);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10001;
    display: none;
    
}

@media (max-width: 1280px){
    header{
        padding: 14px 2%;
        transition: .2s;
    }
    .navbar a{
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    .logo i{
        color: var(--color-font);
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-right: 3px;
    }
    
    .logo span{
        color: var(--color-font);
        font-size: 1.9rem;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1090px){
    #menu-icon{
        font-size: 35px;
        display:block;
    }
    .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: -100%;
        width: 270px;
        height: 29vh;
        background: var(--color-navbar);
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: var(--color-secondary);
        border-width: 2px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all .50s ease;
    }
    .navbar a{
        display: block;
        margin: 12px 0;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        transition: all .50s ease;
    }
    .navbar a:hover{
        color: var(--color-secondary);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    .navbar a.active{
        color: var(--color-secondary);
    }
    .navbar.open{
        right: 2%;
    }
}
```

**Pomodoro:**
*pomodoro_index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>

    <!-- FONT -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    
    
    <!-- ICONS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f48ea54834.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pomodoro_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">


</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"><span>Plan Ahead&nbsp;</span>
            <i>
                <img src="../images_library/pen_and_square.png" width="35" height="35">
            </i>
        </a>

        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Pomodoro</a></li>
            <li><a href="../todo/todo_html.html">To-Do List</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="main">
            <div id="menu-icon">
                <img src="../images_library/menu.png" width="35" height="35">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>


            <div class="painel">
                <p id="work">work</p>
                <p id="break">break</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="time">
                        <p id="minutes"></p>
                        <p>:</p>
                        <p id="seconds"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="controls">
                <button id="start" onclick="start()">
                    <i>
                        <img src="../images_library/play-button-arrowhead.png" width="35" height="35">
                    </i>
                </button>

                <a id="reset" href="./pomodoro_index.html">
                    <i>
                        <img src="../images_library/refresh-arrow.png" width="35" height="35">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p> 
                    *The Pomodoro Technique is a time management method based on 25-minute stretches of focused work broken by five-minute breaks.
                </p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- SCRIPT -->
    <script src="./pomodoro_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*pomodoro_style.css*

```css
:root {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1rem = 10px */

    --color-primary: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-secondary: hsl(14, 100%, 66%);
    --color-font: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.902);

    --color-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

p,
i,
h1 {
    color: var(--color-font);
}

i {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
}

/* ==== CONTENT ==== */

section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: min(42.5rem, 100%);
    margin-inline: auto;
    /*padding-inline: 2rem;*/
    /*padding-top: 5%;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.painel {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20rem;
    margin-block: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow);
}

.painel p {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.painel p.active {
    opacity: 1;
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.timer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow);
}

.circle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 26rem;
    height: 26rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color-secondary);
    position: relative;
}

.circle::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.time {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.time p {
    font-size: 5.6rem;
}

.time p:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: relative;
    top: -.5rem;
    margin-inline: 1rem;
}

.controls {
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

.controls button {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.controls #reset {
    display: none;
}
```

**And here are the Todo page files:**

*todo_html.html (for some reason it is named not index):*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>

    <!-- FONT -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ICONS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f48ea54834.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./todo_style.css">
    
    

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="../index.html" class="logo"><span>Plan Ahead&nbsp;</span>
            <i>
                <img src="../images_library/pen_and_square.png" width="35" height="35">
            </i>
        </a>

        <ul class="navbar">
            <a href="../index.html" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
            <a href="../pomodoro/pomodoro_index.html" class="navbar-link">Pomodoro</a>
            <a href="#" class="active navbar-link">To-Do List</a>
        </ul>

        <div class="main">
            <div id="menu-icon">
                <img src="../images_library/menu.png" width="35" height="35">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="todo-app">
            <h2>
                To-Do List <img src="images/icon.png">
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Any new tasks for today?">
                <button onmousedown="addTask()">Add</button>
            </div>
            <ul id="list-container">
                <!-- <li class="checked">Task1</li>
                <li>Task 2</li>
                <li>Task 3</li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="todo_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*todo_style.css*

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1rem = 10px */

    --color-primary: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-secondary: hsl(14, 100%, 66%);
    --color-font: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.902);
    --color-input: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.315);
    --color-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --color-success: hsl(115, 100%, 42%);
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    
}

p,
i,
h1 {
    color: var(--color-font);
}

/* ==== CONTENT ==== */

.navbar-link a{
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    /*font-size: 1.6rem;*/
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;

}

.todo-app{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 540px;
    background: var(--color-primary);
    margin: 100px auto 20px;
    padding: 40px 30px 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow);
}

.todo-app h2{
    color: var(--color-font);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.todo-app h2 img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: var(--color-input);
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input{
    flex: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

button{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 50px;
    background: var(--color-secondary);
    color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

/*.navbar_folders a{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}*/

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 50px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

ul li::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(images/unchecked.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: -3px;
    top: 12px;
    left: 8px;
}

ul li.checked{
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before{
    background-image: url(images/checked.png);
}

ul li span{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

ul li span:hover{
    background: #edeef0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  On the Network tab, did all referenced CSS files successfully load?  For any given element in the DOM Explorer, what style rules are being applied to that element?  In what way do those rules differ from what you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661749/how-to-link-a-css-file-from-html-file

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-file-in-another-folder

Comment: Thank you a lot for the advice! Didn't even think about debugging tools for some reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS link source for `style.css` for the to-do page must be incorrect. Because I linked it in my computer correctly and it is rendering the header exactly like the other page. You should check and correct this link's `href` and it will be fixed:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">`

And also if you see a font weight difference then it is because of the font cdn link difference between those 2 pages:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just replace it with the other link and both headers will be exactly the same looking.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1rem = 10px */

    --color-primary: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-secondary: hsl(14, 100%, 66%);
    --color-font: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.902);
    --color-input: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.315);
    --color-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --color-success: hsl(115, 100%, 42%);
    --color-dropdown: hsl(0, 0%, 82%);
    --color-navbar: hsla(0, 0%, 98%, 0.987);
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    /*font-size: 1.6rem;*/
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

p,
i,
h1 {
    color: var(--color-font);
}

header{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: white;
    padding: 28px 12%;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

ul li{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo object{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.logo span{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar_folders a{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar a.navbar-link {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 1.6rem !important;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.navbar a.active{
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main a{
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

#menu-icon{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: var(--color-font);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10001;
    display: none;
    
}

@media (max-width: 1280px){
    header{
        padding: 14px 2%;
        transition: .2s;
    }
    .navbar a{
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    .logo i{
        color: var(--color-font);
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-right: 3px;
    }
    
    .logo span{
        color: var(--color-font);
        font-size: 1.9rem;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1090px){
    #menu-icon{
        font-size: 35px;
        display:block;
    }
    .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: -100%;
        width: 270px;
        height: 29vh;
        background: var(--color-navbar);
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: var(--color-secondary);
        border-width: 2px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all .50s ease;
    }
    .navbar a{
        display: block;
        margin: 12px 0;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        transition: all .50s ease;
    }
    .navbar a:hover{
        color: var(--color-secondary);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    .navbar a.active{
        color: var(--color-secondary);
    }
    .navbar.open{
        right: 2%;
    }
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1rem = 10px */

    --color-primary: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-secondary: hsl(14, 100%, 66%);
    --color-font: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.902);
    --color-input: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.315);
    --color-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --color-success: hsl(115, 100%, 42%);
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    
}

p,
i,
h1 {
    color: var(--color-font);
}

/* ==== CONTENT ==== */

.navbar-link a{
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    /*font-size: 1.6rem;*/
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;

}

.todo-app{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 540px;
    background: var(--color-primary);
    margin: 100px auto 20px;
    padding: 40px 30px 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px var(--color-shadow);
}

.todo-app h2{
    color: var(--color-font);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.todo-app h2 img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: var(--color-input);
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input{
    flex: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

button{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 50px;
    background: var(--color-secondary);
    color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

/*.navbar_folders a{
    color: var(--color-font);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}*/

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 50px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

ul li::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(images/unchecked.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: -3px;
    top: 12px;
    left: 8px;
}

ul li.checked{
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before{
    background-image: url(images/checked.png);
}

ul li span{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

ul li span:hover{
    background: #edeef0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>

    <!-- FONT -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ICONS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f48ea54834.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="../index.html" class="logo"><span>Plan Ahead&nbsp;</span>
            <i>
                <img src="../images_library/pen_and_square.png" width="35" height="35">
            </i>
        </a>

        <ul class="navbar">
            <a href="../index.html" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
            <a href="../pomodoro/pomodoro_index.html" class="navbar-link">Pomodoro</a>
            <a href="#" class="active navbar-link">To-Do List</a>
        </ul>

        <div class="main">
            <div id="menu-icon">
                <img src="../images_library/menu.png" width="35" height="35">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="todo-app">
            <h2>
                To-Do List <img src="images/icon.png">
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Any new tasks for today?">
                <button onmousedown="addTask()">Add</button>
            </div>
            <ul id="list-container">
                <!-- <li class="checked">Task1</li>
                <li>Task 2</li>
                <li>Task 3</li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="todo_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough! It is when you look at your code long enough you can't see the obvious things like the Google Fonts being diferent xD. You saved me)

Comment: You are welcome and 'yes' it happens :)